# Создание отчётов в JasperReports Server

Tags: jasperreports

Сейчас я строю отчёты с помощью JasperReports Server следующим образом:

1. в Jaspersoft Studio создаю шаблон отчёта (.jrxml файл)
2. создаю отчёт в JasperReports Server, указываю в качестве источника
   этот, созданный на предыдущем шаге, .jrxml файл (в настройке *Locate 
   the JRXML file* выбираю *Upload a Local File* и указываю путь к этому
   файлу)

После этого я создаю шедулер, отчёты успешно строятся. Но меня интересует вопрос: можно ли создавать шаблон отчёта (.jrxml файл) в самом JasperReports Server, не прибегая к помощи Jaspersoft Studio?

**UPD**
Я нашла способ связать Jaspersoft Studio с JasperReports Server, нажав кнопку *Create JasperReports Server Connection* во вкладке Repository Explorer:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

после чего появилась возможность обновлять макеты в JasperReports Server из Jaspersoft Studio:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но, может быть, можно всё-таки сделать это ещё легче, с каким-нибудь встроенным в JasperReports Server дизайнером макетов?..